# Control sent data to a CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, excel, arduino, vba

In my project I measure the current and the voltage of a solar panel by Arduino and transfer the values into c# code which save this values in a CSV file.
Since serial communication is used I am getting a lot of repeated values or undesired ones.
I have implemented in my c# project exactly the same code in this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp
And I have used it like this in my code (to read current and voltage):

```
CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
row.Add(PanelsVoltage + "");
row.Add(MeasuredCurrent + "");
writer.WriteRow(row);
writer.Flush();
```

How can I control my values which are sent to the CSV file in my c# code.
I would appreciate any help

Comment: Why do you have "a lot of repeated values or undesired ones" "Since serial communication is used"? You only get what you send at the other end, so you should just receive the data you are sending....

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible way to do this would be to store somewhere the values that you have already written to the CSV, and then filter duplicates out in code before writing to the file.

Otherwise, you end up with a lot of file reads to check the contents of the CSV file.

If I were you, I would store the data in memory as well as in the CSV file, then check against the data in memory to see if it is a duplicate before adding to the CSV.

For example, you could have an object `PanelReading` which stores the current and voltage, then a `List<PanelReading>` that your program stores those `PanelReading` objects in (creating them from the serial data); and checks for duplicates:

```
list.Contains(p=>p.Current == readValue.Current && p.Voltage == readValue.Voltage)
```

Something like that.